# Is there a javascript physics engine that does not require canvas?

Tags: physics, javascript

I just need a really simple and small physics engine for squares or circles that moves images using javascript. For the project that I am working on, I can't use canvas, so I will be moving the images via the dom. If I understand it correctly, Box2D and PhysicsJS both require the canvas (or at least in my testing that seemed to be the case). I don't really want to make my own, because I bet there is something out there that already does this.

So, is there a javascript physics engine that does not require canvas?

Comment: This question should not be closed as a "which technology to use" question, because the requirements are sufficiently narrow and specific that an opinion-based discussion and listing of favorite technologies is unlikely to happen. It will likely still get closed because our moderators are usually more interested in enforcing the rule to the letter than to the intention.

Comment: Box2D-JS definitely does not require canvas.

Comment: @Philipp I disagree. Almost every physics engine is decoupled from rendering. That reduces this to a Big List, [which is off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki). (If you have issues with site moderation, ask on [meta](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/).)

Answer (score 7):

A physics engine being tied to a particular renderer shows horrible separation of concerns and really shouldn't happen.

In fact, it doesn't. Box2D-js *can* visualise the simulation with a canvas, but is in no way required to do so. It is possible to extract the information you want and drive some other visualisation with it. [PhysicsJS](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/) has [a custom renderer tutorial](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/tutorials/creating-a-custom-renderer), [as does Matter.js](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/wiki/Rendering#using-a-custom-renderer).

[Here's a list of a bunch more suitable engines](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/3016-list-of-javascript-2d-physics-engines/).